# "It is not all arteries and muscle: it feels too."

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Your eyes will not see this anguished plea. This was only to lighten
>   my over-burdened heart. It is not all arteries and muscle: it feels
>   too.

What does the phrase "it is not all arteries and muscle: it feels too" mean in this context?

Comment: The over-burdened heart is not simply a physical thing ("all arteries and muscles") but also has subjective feelings ("it feels too").  The heart is being personified as a separate thing, a common trope (once upon a time) in Petrarchist poetry.

Comment: The intended meaning might be more clear if you insert a comma after *feels*.

Answer (score 1):

In English and other languages (I believe), the heart is regarded as the "seat of emotions". Love, for example, is something one "feels in the heart".

The contrast in the quote is between the heart as a physical organ studied in biological fashion, and the heart as the "seat of emotions".

Comment: Just for completeness, in the tripartite view of man, 'heart' is sometimes used synonymously with 'spirit' (but sometimes with 'soul' or 'emotional component of soul'), and in the bipartite view/model, with 'spirit/soul complex'.